# from the woocommerce API getting JSON in web browser but not in xcode 8

Tags: ios, json, woocommerce, xcode8

from the woocommerce API getting JSON in web browser but not in xcode 8. When I tried to parse the data with serialization method,in xcode console it is showing nil as the response.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

       let urlString = "urlString"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    downloadJsonWithURl()

    }
    func downloadJsonWithURl(){

        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as? URL)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
           // print (data)
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary{
               // print(jsonObj?.value(forKey:"address"))
                print (jsonObj)


            }
        })       .resume()
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you check error in the completionHandler?

Answer (score 0):

actually API was sending data in form of nested arrays. on parsing that data with online tools it gives me error. So i did a try and hit with  replacing NSDictionary to NSArray. that's all.